# dsPic33f : How to interface ECAN with CAN High/Low Signal

Tags: microcontroller, pic, schematics, microchip, can

I want to start communication between (dsPic33f) ECAN_Module & [PCAN-USB ADAPTER](http://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-USB.199.0.html.)

I have downloaded a demo code [AN1249](http://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en539328) from microchip website.

I am using Explorer-16 board for Testing.

Now the Issue I am facing is connecting PCAN-USB ADAPTER with Explorer-16 board or dsPic33fj256GP710A ??

dsPic33f has two CAN pin C1RX (CAN_Receiver) & C1TX (CAN_Transmitter).

While PCAN-USB Adapter has CAN_HI & CAN_LOW.

How to make connections to start Communication ???

Do i need any CAN IC to complete the interface ??

I tried to study ECAN reference Manual. But could'nt trace out about connections.

This is my very First CAN communication testing code.

So please share me some knowledge/links so that I can proceed further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect CAN_TX and CAN_RX to a CAN transceiver such as an 
[MCP2561](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP2561).  The CAN transceiver will provide the CAN_HI and CAN_LOW signals.  For an example, look at how they implemented the [dsPIC33EV 5V CAN-LIN STARTER KIT](http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=dm330018&utm_source=PR&utm_medium=Press-Release&utm_term=dsPIC33EV_5V_Family_PR_11-25-14&utm_content=MCU16&utm_campaign=dsPIC33EV%205V%20CAN-LIN%20Starter%20Kit) evaluation board.  The schematic for the evaluation board can be found in Appendix A of the [dsPIC33EV 5V CAN-LIN
Starter Kit User’s Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002311A.pdf).